# Error: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 16 from regexp

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I got error on stored procedure for sorting alphanumeric values
The Error was

Procedure execution failed

1139 - Got error 'lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 16' from regexp

I got error on this line

```html
CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(res_no, '(?<=\\()[0-9]+(?=\\))') AS UNSIGNED),
```

Comment: is your DB version 8+ ?

Comment: 10.1.35-MariaDB @ Barbaros Özhan

Comment: It seems to work OK in a stored procedure: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=7d2ab91182db6a50c11f7d2897f47f81

Comment: Are you using dynamic SQL?